# SQL-инъекции, как бороться?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Доброго времени суток. 
В разрабатываемом приложении работа с данными БД происходит через запросы, формируемые следующим образом (например данный запрос):

```
using (SQLiteDataReader rdr = Connection.ExecuteData($"SELECT Club,ChallengeName,Place,NumberOfMedals FROM List WHERE FIO = '{comboBox1.Text}'"))
```

очевидно, что используемый мной метод опасен на предмет внедрения всевозможного "нежелательного" кода.

Как можно от этого обезопаситься? Единственным ли решением является создание репозитория, и собственно хранение всех запросов в фиксированном виде(хранимые процедуры)?

Comment: параметризацией запросов

Comment: @Igor, то есть, если в запросе учитывается более 20 параметров их все необходимо параметризировать? Ладно когда их пара...

Comment: Да,  все. Если неудобно руками подставлять значения параметров - возьмите dapper

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/csharp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хранимые процедуры также защищают от SQL инъекций (если не исполнять внутри процедуры динамический SQL, используя `execute`, `sp_executesql`, и т.д.), как и параметризованные SQL запросы. Параметры процедур используются вместо [литералов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)). SQL инъекция в этом случае не отработает и, скорее всего, вызовет ошибку или не вернет искомые данные.

Пример (SQL Server):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.getDetails @FIO nvarchar(100)
AS
SELECT Club,ChallengeName,Place,NumberOfMedals
FROM List
WHERE FIO = @FIO 
GO
```

Даже если передать в в качества параметра строку:

```
"'Иванов'; DROP TABLE students;"
```

, то комманда `DROP TABLE ...` не выполнится.

PS [ссылка на документацию об использовании параметров в хранимых процедурах в для C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649451.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Надежными способами являются

- Параметризация запросов
- Использование ORM

Репозиторий и хранимые процедуры никак проблему инъекций не решают.

Comment: `хранимые процедуры никак проблему инъекций не решают` - если не выполнять динамический SQL (`execute`, `sp_executesql`, etc.) в хранимой процедуре, то решают...

Comment: @MaxU ок, как хранимая процедура решает проблему инъекции на примере кода из вопроса?

Comment: @MaxU я к тому, что проблема же не в формате запроса (ad hoc / хранимка). Проблема  в способе передаче параметров из C# в SQL. А где и как написан код запроса, в которых эти параметры подставляются - без разницы.

Comment: Напишите `stored procedure`, принимающую `FIO` в качестве параметра - и попробуйте сделать `SQL injection` - СУБД вернет ошибку...

Comment: @MaxU и как будет выглядеть вызов такой процедуры из C# без передачи параметров через строго типизированные параметры?

Comment: примерно так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7542564/5741205 - приходится гуглить, т.к. `C#` я не знаю, но знаю как работают хранимые процедуры на стороне БД... В общем, фраза "хранимые процедуры никак проблему инъекций не решают" - не верна, по-моему...

Comment: @MaxU вы привели ссылку на вызов процедуры с передачей параметров через cmd.Parameters. Это и есть параметризация и именно она дает защиту от инъекций, а не процедура сама по себе - т.е. можно в примере из вопроса написать `... WHERE FIO = @fio`, и сделать `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fio", comboBox1.Text)` - и инъекции не будет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75418/discussion-between-maxu-and-pashapash).

Comment: [-1 за неверную фразу`"хранимые процедуры никак проблему инъекций не решают"`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/68701/how-does-stored-procedure-prevents-sql-injection). если не выполнять динамический SQL (`execute`, `sp_executesql`, etc.) в хранимой процедуре, то решают

Comment: @MaxU отсутсвие динамического SQL в хранимке никак не защищает от инъекции вида `"exec someSP(" + myparam +")"` при вызове этой хранимки из C# (если напороть при вызове). Защищает не вынос кода в хранимку, защищает параметризация запроса при вызове хранимки. Точно так же она защищает и для ad hoc запросов.